# SQL subquery: How to grap the record with both the min(date) and min(hour)

Tags: sql, minimum, correlated-subquery

I have a table from which I want to grap the first record that gives a passage IN ('B410','B420','C430','C440'). So, I suppose this means looking for the record with the oldest date and within that oldest date the record with the oldest time stamp.

[image: table]

I wrote a query with 2 nested subqueries, but that query does not do the trick (it gives me an empty result). What am I doing wrong? The strange thing is that when changing the syntax to find the max(fromdate) and max(hour), I do find the record with timstamp 22:18. But I do not find the record with timestamp 16:40 with min(fromdate) and min(hour).

```
select v.id,
    h.fromdate,
    h.hour,
    h.department,
    h.room
from visit v
inner join visit_hist h
on  v.id = h.id
where v.id in ('10251183')
    and h.room in ('B410','B420','C430','C440')
    and h.fromdate =
    (select min(fromdate)
    from visit_hist
    where (id= h.id
        and h.hour =
        (select min(hour) from visit_hist where id= h.id and h.date = date
        ))
    )
order by v.date,
    v.visit_id;
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server (by looking at the screenshot)?

Comment: looks like SQLS from that screenshot of management studio

Comment: @bertusian so you have your date and your time stored in different columns? (I'll never understand why people do this..). Please post a screenshot of what you see when you right click your table and choose Design.. or alternatively, right click the table, choose SCRIPT AS>>CREATE TABLE to NEW QUERY WINDOW and post that text

Comment: yes, I use SQL server Management studio. Date and time are indeed stored in different columns.

Comment: @Caius Jard, is it possible that I do not have persmissions to do that command. I cannot see it when right clicking the table.

Comment: it's unlikely, but possible; expand the table node so we can see the column list and post a screenshot of that part if it includes the column types

Comment: @ Caius Jard, see picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use window functions:

```
select . . .
from visit v inner join
     (select vh.*, row_number() over (partition by vh.id order by date asc, hour asc) as seqnum
      from visit_hist vh
      where vh.room in ('B410', 'B420', 'C430', 'C440')
     ) vh
     on v.id = vh.id
where v.id in (10251183) and seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This gives the `id`s with the first room in the list.  If you want the `id`s whose first room is in the list, then move the condition on `vh.room` to the outer query.

Comment: @ Gordon, I filtered the results to only one visit_id,  but I want to do run that query on thousands of visit_id's. How does that change the solution you suggested?

Comment: @Bertusian . . . The code should work even if you remove the filter on `v.id`.